# the usage of - when it comes to / regarding

Tags: word-usage

> I think I can develop how to express how I feel by drawing pictures, which I think is also important ***(when it comes to / regarding)*** human interactions in that we communicate by expressing how we feel.

which one is proper here?

Comment: "When it comes to" would be more natural in that sentence, but I can't really explain why other than "it just sounds better to my ear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be used. "When it comes to" <-> "regarding".

"when it comes to" is idiomatic.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/when+it+comes+to:

"when it comes to something
as for something; speaking about something."

"regarding" is prepositional.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/regarding

"re·gard·ing . . .
prep.
In reference to; with respect to; concerning [something]."

Your choice whether you want to sound idiomatic or not.